# Undefined offset in Stomp Client

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to activeMq broker using a Stomp Client source code. I have downloaded Stomp.php and when I run examples it shows the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\Stomp.php on line 368
>   StompFrame Object ( [command] => 1 [headers] => Array ( ) [body] => )

This error is caused by line 368:

```
list ($header, $body) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
```

Comment: Your question will get more useful attention if you give it a more meaningful title (e.g. what causes undefined offset error using Stomp Client), and ask a clear question (not just "please help"), and add more tags (something about Stomp? About active Mq?), and show more of your code. What you have here doesn't give your helpers much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$data` does not contain `\n\n`, so `explode()` only returns one item

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same resulting error due to trying to use AMQP port instead of STOMP port of RabbitMQ. You might experience a different issue with connection to RabbitMQ though.

Answer (score -1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 'Off');
```

If you havent checked for what you are getting in your arrey then  offset error 2 will show because of array is not getting what it expects to get and so you should put the above on the top of the file to disable the html errors.